# Why does a UIColor's values change after serialization/deserialization?

Tags: ios, serialization, uicolor, nskeyedarchiver

If you create a color and then run `[color isEqual:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:color]]]`, you'll find the answer may be NO, at least in my testing with values between 0 and 1 exclusive. The new color is very, very close, but it's not exactly the same as the old color, at least in terms of its internal representation. Perhaps it has the same actual output color though, considering it's using 64 bits to represent what only needs 8 bits.

Any ideas?

Comment: Update your question with relevant code. Show the before and after values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this has to do with the representation of the color when is serialized. It might be represented as a float and if so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36512953/1949494) could happen. I think you could avoid this if you implement your own serialisation, using string or something else.